# Unable to load DLL when running the C# project

Tags: c#, c++, dll, dllimport, cppsharp

I am attempting to develop a simple CppSharp project.
The implementation of the header file is as follows:

```
class Sample 
{
public:
    int a;
    int b;
    Sample(int a, int b){
        this->a=a;
        this->b=b;
    };
};
```

The implementation of the Setup function in the ILibrary interface is as follows:

```
public void Setup(Driver driver)
{
    //throw new NotImplementedException(); 
    var options = driver.Options;
    options.GeneratorKind = GeneratorKind.CSharp;
    options.OutputDir = @"D:\Project\Cppsharp\Sample\output";
    var module = options.AddModule("CppClass");
    module.IncludeDirs.Add(@"D:\Project\Cppsharp\Sample\include");
    module.Headers.Add("Sample.h");
}
```

Upon execution of

```
ConsoleDriver.Run(new CppClass()),
```

two files named CppClass.cs and CppClass-symbols.cpp are generated within the designated folder. The files CppClass.cs and CppClass-symbols.cpp are copied into the C# project, and a Sample object is instantiated using

```
CppClass.Sample sample = new CppClass.Sample(1,2)
```

However, upon running the C# project, an error message of "Unable to load DLL 'CppClass' or one of its dependencies" arises. Could you kindly advise on what steps I may be omitting?

Comment: You should export Sample class with __declspec. E.g. class __declspec(dllexport) Sample

Comment: Ensure the dll is builtt and availabele,Place the Dll in the correct location,check for missing dependenciesare you using the right compiler settings?